# Designing K8 pod and proceses for initialization

Tags: kubernetes

I have a problem statement where in there is a Kubernetes cluster and I have some pods running on it.
Now, I want some functions/processes to run once per deployment, independent of number of replicas.

1. These processes use the same image like the image in deployment yaml.
2. I cannot use initcontainers and sidecars, because they will run along with main container on pod for each replica.

I tried to create a new image and then a pod out of it. But this pod keeps on running, which is not good for cluster resource, as it should be destroyed after it has done its job. Also, the main container depends on the completion on this process, in order to run the "command" part of K8 spec.

Looking for suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like a job: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/

Comment: @KM09 Is the above solution the one you are looking for?

Comment: @JulianoCosta thank you for the suggestion, and yes that partly solves the purpose.

Comment: But, I also want the main container to wait for this process to finish, before starting its own processes.

Comment: @KM09 Is there anything you have tried already? We need a reproducible example to work with.

Comment: I tackled this problem, by creating a Job with TTL, so that the Job pod is destroyed after job finished its work. (TTL is still an alpha feature). And as for the deployment, I raised the initial delay seconds and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, You could write an [admission controller webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) for intercepting create/update deployments and triggering your functions as you want. If your functions need to be checked, use `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration` for validating the process and then deny or accept commands.